# Problem showing tableView updates while parsing xml with AQXMLParser StreamingParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing, streaming

I have a tableview which gets filled by a StreamingXMLParser (https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit). 
When I run my app, the tableView appears empty.
First I thought that my tableView didn't show anything until the async xml parser was ready, but if I start to scroll during the parsing the view is suddenly filled.

My code is based on ParserExample (https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/ParserExample) and the parser is called using the same method as the example:

```
[parser parseAsynchronouslyUsingRunLoop: [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                                            mode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                               notifyingDelegate: self
                                        selector: @selector(parser:completedOK:)
                                         context: NULL]
```

I think my problem is that my async task is taking up too much processing power.
Who has experience with the StreamingXMLParser and can help me out?
How can I fix my app so the tableView has more priority than the xml parsing ?

The problem can be simulated by downloading the example project and inserting
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.2];
After the [self.managedObjectContext save: NULL]; statement in the endPost method of the parserDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to circumvent the problem by calling the synchronous method [parser parse] via a small utility called MBProgressHUD Created by Matej Bukovinski.
The MBProgressHUD now calls the parsing method async & fixes my problem. (And gives a nice indicator).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your parsing. Because when you parse some tags they have some empty or `\n` string so the first few have empty rows. One more thing that can happen is that the response from the server is coming too late. That's why it takes so much time.

You should place some break points and then check each data.

Comment: No, that's not it. It had got something to do with the way the asynchronous call is setup. I've opened a bug in github to the developer to see if he can help me out.